# Software Center - "Edit->Software Sources" disabled

Tags: software-center, software-sources

I am trying to download winHQ from [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

When trying to add the WineHQ PPA Repository (as detailed in the link above) after opening **Ubuntu Software Center** I cannot select **Edit->Software Sources**. The menu item is disabled

I am using Ubuntu 13.10

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add it from a terminal, just type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: thanks darent, I tried but I get an error
sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found

Comment: Sorry, try the same with sudo add-apt-repository instead (one of those is default, the other has to be installed)